How best would airmobile/air assault tactics be employed in a medieval setting?
In my current setting - alongside tactics typical of late medieval warfare - the riding of various species of flying creatures is commonplace in battle.
While these are commonly employed in typical ways - climactic aerial duels between cavalrymen and such - one concept I had concerns a group which specialises in air assault tactics using one of these types of flying creatures - large mollusks which can inflate themselves with flammable, lighter-than-air gas and "swim" through the air.
While their fragile constitutions and sluggish flight (~70km/h) make them ill-suited to either direct ground attack (A variety of methods having been concocted by ground infantry to counter aerial threats), or battling other, more combat-capable airborne creatures, they are capable of carrying more weight than anything else in the sky, equivalent to roughly twelve soldiers at a time. This makes them tremendously useful in a logistical sense, but also as an asset for rapidly maneuvering troops in a battlefield.
These air assault soldiers consist of highly-trained infantrymen capable of both fighting in a shield wall formation, throwing javelins, and rapidly constructing fortifications, to either outmaneuver and outflank an enemy, or secure their landing zone for further aerial reinforcements.
Would air assault tactics actually be useful in a setting where warfare is restricted to melee combat, cavalry and archery? Are the small amounts of soldiers these creatures could carry capable of having any significant effect against thousands-strong infantry and cavalry formations?
If so, how best could they be employed to defeat an enemy?

How best to defeat an enemy is entirely dependent upon the specific circumstances of a particular enemy. That's like asking how best to beat the game of chess. You can't talk about that without needing to address the choices an opponent makes in response to your actions. If the question is meaningless on the simplified system of a chessboard how exactly are we to answer with all the complications added.

OK, so your "blimps" have roughly the payload of a Huey, roughly the speed of a Huey (somewhat slower, but so is probably everyone), and highly vulnerable to ground fire (with flaming arrows).
Historically, the heyday of the Huey was the sort-of-counterinsurgency fight in Vietnam. Not exactly a counterinsurgency, because the VC was not exactly an insurgency, but the Huey prospered against guerilla on foot with rifles and machine guns. Airmobile forces with similar weapons as their enemies and much better fire support could be airlifted around the envelope of the guerilla weapons, to outflank and overtake them. Using such a tactic against the Red Army of that era would have been suicidal.
Airborne forces were supposed to delay the Soviets by digging in and waiting for ground reinforcements. They dropped from bigger, faster aircraft and they carried a high proportion of ATGMs.
So what can your blimpborne infantry do?
Shields and javelins and fortifications sound like Roman legions.
On the ground, your infantry are much less mobile than light cavalry, and probably less heavily armored than heavy infantry (a difference to the Romans, compared to most of their enemies).  If they really carry javelins, they will probably be outranged by archers, and they probably cannot man those fortifications they are supposed to build unless you introduce literally hundreds of those "blimps."
"Vertical envelopment" implies something like battle lines and situational awareness which did not exist in medieval times. (Do your other flyers help in this regard?) Medieval battles happened when both sides agreed to give field battle -- there were cases where heralds arranged the battlefield in advance -- or where one side is pushed back into a fortification it must hold.
Raid and Pillage
With their speed and range, your airmobile infantry can strike deep into the hinterland of the enemy. Two or three "blimps," two or three dozen light infantry with swords and bows, putting a manor to the torch. Disappear before the enemy can react. Force the enemy to garrison all those manors with "penny packets" because the wealthy owners call for defense.
River Crossing
The ability to secure a bridgehead reduces the value of rivers to the defender. (Compare how the Rhine complemented the Roman Limes.)
Logistics for Light Cavalry.
Cavalry which has to forage is much less efficient. Your "blimps" can carry a ton of supplies, presumably many miles.

Many good points, especially raiding and pillaging.  People often don't realize that in Medieval warfare, the battlefield where thousands of guys slugged it out with thousands of other guys was a rare occurrence,often interspaced by months of raiding by small parties of men to interfere with and secure supply lines.

If they could fly higher than arrows they would be invincible. You could just drop stones on the other army. You could hover above their commanders tent and drop burning oil. Fly over city walls.

Are the small amounts of soldiers these creatures could carry capable of having any significant effect against thousands-strong infantry and cavalry formations?

I'd use them to target the enemy leaders and communications and logistics units. Or burn their camp where they have their plunder and women & kids, supplies etc,.

They presumably wouldn't be invincible to other flying creatures, but yes. If they can carry twelve men, they can also carry two men and a lot of ammunition. Effectively you now have fighter and bomber aircraft. They can fly over city walls, fly across rivers where the fords are guarded, fly across swamps or other difficult terrain. Everything airborne troops do IRL.

Considering that air units are ubiquitous, this seems unrealistic since dropping stuff from high up is notoriously inaccurate and more nimble aerial knights could just pick them off.

@Nosajimiki that hasn't stopped bomber aircraft being used throughout the 20th century.

@user111403 I was contesting your statement that "they would be invincible" which has never been true of bombers. And... actually it did.  In WWI, they experimented with bombers, but canceled their use on both sides of the conflict because they were too ineffective.   It took the much more advanced planes of WWII before bombing became even sort-of effective.

@Nosajimiki - that wasn't my statement, if you look at the first comment above you'll see I expressed the same doubt about invincibility. "In WWI they experimented with bombers, but canceled on both sides" - I'm not an expert, but I know for a fact that the Germans raided London with Gothas and R-series bombers throughout 1917-18, so I'd really like to see a source for that. They did largely restrict them to night raids, as both sides did for most of WWII.

Finally, I'll note that there's a huge difference in range between even WWI AA and medieval arrows. These creatures are able to fly much lower compared to later aircraft, and probably even hover briefly, which will do wonders for accuracy. No, they won't be able to pick off individuals with rocks, but target large formations, or drop Greek fire on camps, cities and ships - yes, absolutely.

@user111403 sorry, I meant that they canceled trying to use bombers to hit targets of military importance.  After they realized they could not be used to hit trenches or specific factories or warehouses, they diverted to using bombers to indiscriminately bomb cities out of not wanting to waste their investment, but even that mostly ended 3 months before the war ended when Peter Strasser was killed in action.

@Nosajimiki sorry, still skeptical. (did some reading) the Germans continued to develop and order large numbers of G-series bombers throughout the end of the war, so it wasn't just not wasting investment. They did eventually give up on bombing London (due to losses more than being unable to hit anything), but continued to build tactical bombers. Meanwhile on the British side, Handley Page built the V/1500 in summer 1918 explicitly to reach Berlin, the war ended just in time to stop it being used.

@user111403 You are still missing the point about what they were bombing.  They were indiscriminately bombing cities meaning they were only concerned with killing random people, not achieving any tactical objectives. They were not even able to hit specific factories and warehouses with any reliability.  As for hovering, you'd be surprised at how hard even that is.  Veritasium did a video a while back dropping kinetic projectiles from a helicopter, and even using GPS assistance, they could not get close to target accurate at heights of more than a few dozen meters.

@Nosajimiki I am not, in fact, missing the point. I am stating that major powers considered bomber aircraft worth investing in despite serious limitations, and also that the height and speed requirements which are the greatest limits to accuracy don't apply. These creatures should be able to achieve accuracy closer to low-level ground attack aircraft than to high-altitude bombers. They are limited by not having high explosive, but they can use fire, which can be tactically powerful as well as devastating to a medieval city.

If you share a link, I'll check out the Veritasium video, but note that he hasn't (I assume) spent a lifetime or even a couple years training to drop things off helicopters. These guys will if that's the peak of military technology, and it will make a difference.

Frame challenge: As lighter-than-air fliers, these creatures can presumably stay in the air for rather longer than flapping-wing creatures? They'll also have a much smoother ride.
That gives them a significant advantage in reconnaissance, the simplest and most obvious use of aviation in war. Without photography, aerial observers will have to sketch enemy positions and fortifications, which is much easier if you don't have large wings beating close by.
Of course, the enemy will send up combat fliers to chase them off, which allows setting traps where a larger group of your own fliers dive out of the sun to protect the observation oyster.
This was the pattern of events in the air over the Western Front in the first year of WWI, and which gives you rich stores of ideas and imagery to use for your plots.

You should set your story a couple of centuries later
In the late medieval period, 12 men are already going to accomplish extremely little. However, state capacity is not yet high enough to maintain a large stable of these creatures. If they can carry the load of a helicopter, they probably take up the space of a helicopter, and eat like a helicopter too. For the logistical strain that a meaningful number of these creatures would put on your armies, it's much more effective to roll up with several hundred additional men.
But in the early modern period, when state capacity is rapidly improving, an army might be able to scrape together a few dozen blimps at once. And this makes all the difference - because a defender needs to be strong everywhere, but an attacker only needs to be strong in one place. Being able to choose where to attack will make a force of a couple hundred men extremely useful, if you deploy it right.
These blimps are still pretty useless over the course of a battle but they are excellent raiders, dashing deep into enemy territory under the cover of night and taking out bridges, supply depots, messenger posts, and other vulnerable infrastructure.
Keep in mind that your ability to gather real-time intel is pretty much non-existent. Mobile targets like command posts will be able to elude your attacks, and even newer construction won't be marked on any of your maps (unless you manage to steal them).
Bombing is also completely out - simply dropping something over the side from any significant elevation is never going to let you hit a target smaller than a city block. Your commandos would need to land to do their dirty deeds.


Would air assault tactics actually be useful in a setting where warfare is restricted to melee combat, cavalry and archery? Are the small amounts of soldiers these creatures could carry capable of having any significant effect against thousands-strong infantry and cavalry formations? If so, how best could they be employed to defeat an enemy?

Bombardment. 70 km/h is plenty if you can beeline to target. Load small stones, drop from 200 m. Everything is just dead.
"A variety of methods having been concocted by ground infantry to counter aerial threats" - nope. Still a problem, even in 21st century.

Mixed combat
These creatures in many ways resemble the bombers in the olden days. As a writer this is great! You can use this to enhance the story with something familiar. Look at Star Wars, where the trench run was a direct adaptation of an assault on a dam, or many other space battles represented naval battles in various periods, adapted for space.
Your creatures aren't useless, though they do have many weaknesses of the old bombers. They are slow and unwieldy compared to their 'fighter' counterparts. Because of their higher weight limits they also aren't defenceless. They can carry more armour and troops. This translates to a higher capacity of throwing stuff down on the enemy and 'gunner' positions to ward off attack.
However, you would not send them out alone. Many bombers of the era bombed alone, because fighters didn't have the range. Regardless, for a long distance of the flight and wherever possible they were augmented by fighters. Put in your fast flyers next to your slow as molasses flying creatures. They screen the bombers against attack, engaging anyone who gets too close.
They double as a transport. The opportunities are mixed. Putting down a few soldiers can be practically suicide, or a genius move in anything from guerilla warfare, to (food/ammunition) logistics, or simply enough troops to effectively make an extra front in troop warfare. It has the opportunity, which your plot will decide.
Finally you might use them as blunt weapons. 70km/h is quite fast, and with a certain bulk and armour you could fly low and crush many people.
In short, they have a great potential role. They can drop anything from arrows, rocks and incendiary items in greater quantities and for longer, which is a huge boon in prolonged fights. Though they can defend themselves they are best with a fighter escort. They have some transport capabilities that can be a great asset.

Before the invention of smart bombs, bombing was either done by fast dive bombers which were only accurate within about 30 meters and probably not a good fit for these mounts anyway, or carpet bombers which were only accurate within a few hundred meters meaning  they needed to carry about 30 times the weight of these mounts in fire bombs to be able to saturate an area well enough to matter.  Without at least WWII era explosives, targeting, and carry capacities systems, I don't think bombing will be a practical tactic.

@Nosajimiki just concerns. However, the height and speed is likely less, and the building materials more flammable. In addition, the range of weapons is also less. These allow for more effective bombing. That being said, bombing might not be as viable as real life bombers. This means that either the writer needs to use suspension of disbelief, letting bombers have more utility in a wider range of situations, or their use is simply less than initially suggested. That being said, a 70km/h beast is slow. The fast aerial cavalry that are suggested to do CQC is less viable if you think about it.

Contact explosives were not even invented until the 1800s.  You're not going to be able to use these guys for anything other than dropping rocks.

@Nosajimiki no one said anything about contact explosives? With some creativity you can drop more than rocks though. I expect a line of research will be dedicated to weapons for such creatures. Specialised torches of oil or animal fat. Maybe some cultures have Greek fire. Distilleries could supply the alcohol for molotov cocktails. Just as a quick line of thought. Late medieval has quite the resume of technology. They even had explosives, like early forms of grenades. There's plenty that can be chucked, with quite some risk to the blimp at times.

These mollusks are basically described as hydrogen blimps.  Bringing an open flame onboard one, sounds like a Darwin Award waiting to happen.

There are several missing pieces in OP.
The most important is if these blimp-like objects are able to fly high enough to be safe from archery and ballistas.
Other important detail is how expensive are those things to raise/deploy.
In general two very different usage cases come to mind:

transport of very skilled and undercover agents well within enemy field to perform assassination or sabotage (moonless night might be necessary for safe deployment).
transport highly flammable substances low over enemy troops and then "sacrifice" the blimp to rain fire on surrounding enemies (a 12 soldiers payload can mean A LOT of flammable material akin to Greek pitch). This would be effective also in siege.

